# Zoom meeting install

Tags: software-installation, internet, zoom-meeting

How do i install Zoom Meeting? I have tried terminal, and nothing worked. I have just installed Ubuntu,and tried to get on but no success. None of the files seemed to work either.
How can it work?

Comment: What version is this?

Comment: What errors did you get?

Answer (score 1):

you can download and install Zoom by running the following commands in the terminal

```
wget https://zoom.us/client/latest/zoom_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb
```

If this is also giving you error , then can you share the error statements with me. So that I can help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://websiteforstudents.com/install-zoom-for-linux-client-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04/

follow the above link for ubuntu 16.04 and above...haven't tried in 14.04